# False Vacuum State (QFT)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, field-theory, vacuum, cosmological-inflation

I am wondering if someone can refer me to a proof that the false vacuum state is a natural consequence of scalar field theories? I see that being said in a lot of texts on cosmology when discussing inflation.